# How to send multiple emails in array format to database using GraphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise, graphql

I am recently started working with GraphQL.I want to send multiple emails at a time in array format and sending the request(mutation query) in postman as below.This query is working for inserting one record at a time, but i want to insert multiple emails and usernames at a time.Please give me any suggestions how to query for that. Thank you.

```
 mutation M { 
updateContacts
  (
    _id:"5603ce8abdc210e01834ec62"
    username:"nani" 
   emails:"nani@gmail.com"
   ) 
{mycontacts{username,emails}}}
```

My GraphQL schema is:

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A user',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    },
    mycontacts:{
      type: new GraphQLList(MyContactType)
    }
  })
});

export var MyContactType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MyContact',
  description: 'A mycontact',
  fields: () => ({
    username:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The username.',
    },
    emails:{
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString),
      description: 'The emails.',
    }
  })
});
```

updateContact code like:

```
updateContacts:{
   type: UserType,
   args: {
    _id: {
      type:GraphQLString,
      description: 'The _id of the user.',
    },
    mycontacts:{
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)
    },
     username:{
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The username.',
    },
    emails:{
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString),
      description: 'The emails.',
    }
  },
  resolve: (root,{username,mycontacts,emails,_id}) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      User.findOne({_id:_id},(err,res)=>{
            var data={'username':username,'emails':emails};
           _.each({data}, function (contact) {
                res.mycontacts.push(contact);
                 User.update({_id}, {$set:{mycontacts:res.mycontacts}},  (err,result) => {
            err ?  reject(err) :resolve(User.findOne({'_id':_id}));
         })
        })  
      })
    })
   }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this. But it should work

`mutation M { 
first: updateContacts(_id:"5603ce8abdc210e01834ec62", username:"nani", emails:"nani@gmail.com") 
  {
    mycontacts {
      username,
      emails
    }
  },
  second: updateContacts(_id:"5603ce8abdc210e01834ec62", username:"nani", emails:"nani@gmail.com") 
  {
    mycontacts{
      username,
      emails
    }
  },
  third: updateContacts(_id:"5603ce8abdc210e01834ec62", username:"nani", emails:"nani@gmail.com") 
  {
    mycontacts{
      username,
      emails
    }
  }
}`

Comment: ,Thanks for your response it is working but I need to get the response only once ie. at the end. Not every time. Here I am getting three times regardingly. Please give any simplification for this query.